# Angular js http.post request not hitting my url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular js HTTP.post request not hitting Server. If I change the service name it is working fine.It occurs when I have special characters in my data
Example :

**request with error**

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: serviceUrl,
    data: {"validationkey": "Ff6wxzv06V2csh2yyCa20+_*&%^&$%27%26",
                },
    timeout: 60000,
    crossDomain: true,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

**working request**

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: serviceUrl,
    data: {"validationkey": "Ff6wxzv06V2csh2yyCa20kjhjhjg",
                },
    timeout: 60000,
    crossDomain: true,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Please let me know what can cause this issue

Comment: Do you have a post method defined in the API to support this request?

Comment: Is your `serviceUrl` running?. Can you please post it?

Comment: 1) `crossDomain` isn't a [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) config property. 2) The default `content-type` header is `application/json` so you don't need to set it. 3) Are you checking for any error responses? How about in your browser's *Network* console?

Comment: If you change service name.. what do you mean?

Comment: This is occurring  when I have special character in my data

Comment: What is the error generated ? What do you mean by 'special character' ? Show us the service that is called. What service is working ?